# Scrapy-Selenium: How can I parse multiple JavaScript URLs in SeleniumRequest?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to obtain reviews of your store.
We are using Scrapy and Scrapy-Selenium because JavaScript is used in the middle of the site.

I want to parse multiple URLs to SeleniumRequest for analysis,
but it is not working.
I am able to get multiple URLs.

What should I do in this case?
Any advice you can give me would be appreciated.

```
import scrapy
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class KutiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'review'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://example.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath('//ul[@class="area"]/a/@href')[0].get()
        yield response.follow(url=urls, callback=self.parse_area)

    def parse_area(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="Name"]')
        for url in urls:
            yield response.follow(url=url.xpath('.//h3/a/@href').get(), callback=self.parse_shop)

    def parse_shop(self, response):
        try:
            r = requests.get(response.url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            repo = soup.find('div', {'class': 'Txt'})
        except:
            pass

        urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="viewMore"]/a/@href').get()
        for url in [urls]:
            newurls = response.urljoin(url)
        if urls:
            yield SeleniumRequest(url=str(newurls), screenshot=True, callback=self.parse_thera, wait_time=2)
        try:
            yield {
            'shop_name': response.xpath('//span[@class="now"]/a/span/text()').get(),
            'shop_url': response.xpath('//dd/a/@href').get(),
            'area': response.xpath('//div[@class="Info"]/dl/dt[contains(text(), "")]/following-sibling::dd/text()').get(),
            'report-name': response.xpath('//div[@class="heading"]//span[@class="Name"]/a[1]/text()').get(),
            'report': repo.text
            }
        except:
            pass

　　# Problem code
    def parse_thera(self, response):
        for res in response.url:
            r = res.meta['driver']
            html = r.page_source
            print(html)
```

Comment: Using playwright solved the problem

Comment: `parse_thera`  always get only one URL and you can't use `for... in response.url` because this way you get `for char ins string_with_url`. If you have many urls then you have to send many `SeleniumRequest` - but it seems you have wrong indentations and you run `SeleniumRequest` AFTER `for`-loop but you should do it INSIDE `for`-loop. OR simply remove line `if urls:` (which is useless) and you will have `SeleniumRequest` inside `for`-loop

Comment: @furas thx a lot!  I had a feeling that I was using the for loop incorrectly, so I will review it again.
I also asked a similar question. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71500291/python-playwrights-async-does-not-process-all-of-the-scraped-pages