# Python Playwright's async does not process all of the scraped pages

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, python-asyncio, playwright, playwright-python

Scraping and parsing Javascript pages in Playwright.
There are about 100 URLs, but the process ends without completing all of them.

What could be the cause of this?
The code is working so far.

Is the for syntax in the wrong place?

I would appreciate it if you could tell me if I am using async incorrectly.

**Changed to current code.**
The following commands are executed in Scrapy.
scrapy runspider kuti_info.py

```
import scrapy
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import asyncio

class KutiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'kuti'
    allowed_domains = ['xxxxxxx.jp']
    start_urls = ['https://xxxxxxx.jp/']


    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath('//ul[@class="areaList"]/a/@href')[0].get()
        yield response.follow(url=urls, callback=self.parse_area)

        # urls = response.xpath('//ul[@class="areaList"]')
        # for url in urls:
        #     yield response.follow(url=url.xpath('.//a/@href').get(), callback=self.parse_area)


    def parse_area(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="salonName"]')
        for url in urls:

            yield response.follow(url=url.xpath('.//h3/a/@href').get(), callback=self.parse_shop)


        # next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="pager"]//li/a[contains(text(), "次へ")]/@href').get()
        # if next_page:
        #     yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_area)

    async def parse_shop(self, response):
        try:
            r = requests.get(response.url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            repo = soup.find('div', {'class': 'abbr uTxt'})
        except:
            pass

        urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="viewMore"]/a/@href').get()
        for url in [urls]:
            newurls = response.urljoin(url) href="/therapistlist.php?id=!!!!"
            yield response.follow(url=newurls, callback=self.parse_therapist)

        # yield SeleniumRequest(url=str(newurls), screenshot=True, callback=self.parse_therapist, wait_time=2)
        try:
            yield {
            'shop_name': response.xpath('//span[@class="now"]/a/span/text()').get(),
            'shop_url': response.xpath('//dd/a/@href').get(),
            'area': response.xpath('//div[@class="basicInfo"]/dl/dt[contains(text(), "エリア")]/following-sibling::dd/text()').get(),
            'report-therapi-name': response.xpath('//div[@class="heading"]//span[@class="thName"]/a[1]/text()').get(),
            'report': repo.text
            }
        except:
            pass

    async def parse_therapist(self, response):
        with sync_playwright() as p:
            browser = p.chromium.launch()
            page = browser.new_page()
            page.goto(response.url)
            sleep(2)
            html = page.content()
            selector = Selector(text=html)
            idurls =  selector.xpath('//li[@therapist_id]/a/@href').get()
            # browser.close()
            yield response.follow(url=idurls, callback=self.parse_thera_page)

    async def parse_thera_page(self, response):
        with sync_playwright() as p:
            browser = p.chromium.launch()
            page = browser.new_page()
            print(response.url)
            page.goto(response.url)
            sleep(2)
            html = page.content()
            selector = Selector(text=html)
            print(selector.xpath('//p[@class="TopicPath"]/span[@class="now"]/a/span/text()'))
    # try:
    #     r = requests.get(response.url)
    #     soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    #     repo = soup.find('div', {'class': 'txt'})
    # except:
    #     pass
            yield {
            'therapist_name': selector.xpath('//p[@class="TopicPath"]/span[@class="now"]/a/span/text()').get(),
            # 'report': repo.text
            }
```

Comment: always put real url so we could see how it works and test code.

Comment: `get()` can give only one `url`, not many `urls`, and there is no need to use `for`-loop. `for url in [urls]:`  but you can directly use `newurls = response.urljoin(urls)`

Comment: the biggest mistake can be `except: pass` - you may have some error but you can't see it. You should at least display it `except Exception as ex: print('Exception:', ex)`

Comment: Ah OK! It had become a habit to PASS

Comment: I try to run code but it can't find even first `//ul[@class="area"]/a/@href` - maybe because it is only for registered users and it needs first to login. Do you can access your data in web browser without login? If you have to login in web browser then script also has to login.

Comment: @furas I can see the information without logging in. Maybe because it's a Japan server.

Comment: did you login before? It may remeber it. You could also check in other browser, or in `Private mode`

Comment: Maybe `//ul[@class="areaList"]`

Comment: this element I can see - I will check it later

Comment: Thank you. I'll try some things, it's a hurdle for me, I've only been touching Python for a month. I will read your blog.

Comment: i suggest to use `print()`, `print(len(...))`, `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. In some palces I see `.get()` - so you get only first url and you skip other urls and this may give you less results. First you get only first `areaList`,  and later only one therapist from long list ~250 therapists.

Comment: Finally it visit ~47 pages (1 area, other, ~15 shops,~15 therapists) and it scrape ~30 items (in CSV)

Comment: it seems you can get list of therapists as JSON data by adding `&more` to original url https://men-esthe.jp/therapistlist.php?id=72&more so this part may no need `Playwright`

Comment: I'll check the variables by len and type, I didn't know there was such a thing as a "more" parameter.

 I'm getting all therapistlist.php, so I want to get all therapist.php from therapistlist.php

Comment: this page get all data from JSON (which it read using JavaScript) but you can read directly these JSON data  and code runs much, much faster. It gets me ~800 therapists in ~1 minute.

Comment: I see that it says &more in the HTML source. I'll try to get it with a regular expression.

Comment: there is no need to get &more with regular expresion - simply add `&more` to urls which you send with `callback=parse_therapist` and inside `parse_therapist` you can get `data = response.json()` and run loop `for item in data: url = '/therapist.php?id=' + item['id']`. In data you should find other information which can be useful and maybe you will no need to run `parse_thera_page`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see `.get()` in some places so it get only first item from list - ie. it gets first therapist from list ~250 therapists. And maybe this is the problem that you get less results.

I found that `therapistlist.php?id=...` uses JavaScript to read all data as JSON from `therapistlist.php?id=...&more` (with `&more` at the end) and it render page. And this way I read therapistlist as JSON data without `Playwright` so I get results much,much faster.

I get ~800 therapists in ~1 minute.

If you write data in CSV then you may have another problem.
In CSV all items must have the same columns - and if `Scrapy` see `{'therapist_name': ...}` with column `therapist_name` which it doesn't have in `shop data` then it skips it - and you may get file only with shops without therapists. I added field `therapist_name` in shop data and now CSV saves also therapists.

```
import scrapy
from time import sleep
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class KutiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'kuti'
    allowed_domains = ['men-esthe.jp']
    start_urls = ['https://men-esthe.jp/']


    def parse(self, response):
        print('[parse] url:', response.url)
        
        urls = response.xpath('//ul[@class="areaList"]/a/@href')[0].get()
        print('[parse] len(urls):', len(urls), type(urls))
        
        yield response.follow(url=urls, callback=self.parse_area)

        # urls = response.xpath('//ul[@class="areaList"]')
        # for url in urls:
        #     yield response.follow(url=url.xpath('.//a/@href').get(), callback=self.parse_area)


    def parse_area(self, response):
        print('[parse_area] url:', response.url)

        urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="salonName"]')
        print('[parse_area] len(urls):', len(urls), type(urls))

        for url in urls:
            url = url.xpath('.//h3/a/@href').get()
            yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_shop)

        # next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="pager"]//li/a[contains(text(), "次へ")]/@href').get()
        # if next_page:
        #     yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_area)

    def parse_shop(self, response):
        print('[parse_shop] url:', response.url)

        urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="viewMore"]/a/@href')
        print('[parse_shop] len(urls):', len(urls), type(urls))

        for url in urls.getall():
            print('[parse_shop] url:', url)
            yield response.follow(url=url + '&more', callback=self.parse_therapist)

        yield {
            'shop_name': response.xpath('//span[@class="now"]/a/span/text()').get(),
            'shop_url': response.xpath('//dd/a/@href').get(),
            'area': response.xpath('//div[@class="basicInfo"]/dl/dt[contains(text(), "エリア")]/following-sibling::dd/text()').get(),
            'report-therapi-name': response.xpath('//div[@class="heading"]//span[@class="thName"]/a[1]/text()').get(),
            'report': response.css('div.abbr.uTxt').text,
            'therapist_name': "",
        }
            

    def parse_therapist(self, response):
        print('[parse_therapist] url:', response.url)

        data = response.json()

        for item in data:
            url = '/therapist.php?id=' + item['id']
            yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse_thera_page)

    def parse_thera_page(self, response):
        print('[parse_thera_page] url:', response.url)
        
        print('now:', response.xpath('//p[@class="TopicPath"]/span[@class="now"]/a/span/text()'))
        
        yield {
            'shop_name': '',
            'shop_url': '',
            'area': '',
            'report-therapi-name': '',
            'report': '',
            'therapist_name': response.xpath('//p[@class="TopicPath"]/span[@class="now"]/a/span/text()').get(),
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I will try it a little later.

I'm testing with MongoDB Atlas, so I'll check the data storage as well.

 I didn't know there were such kind people in the programming world.

Comment: I get one problem - I run code many times and finally it shows error `401` and page in browser ask to login to get access. Code may runs to fast and server may detect it.

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thank you so much! Login is not requested at the moment, is it because of User agent or something else

Comment: I didn't need login for `areaList` but for `area` it didn't even display for me. maybe it depends on IP, I have no idea and I can't check it.

Comment: Thanks.It seems likely that it will depend on the IP. I am accessing from Japan. By the way
 what are the possible causes when the process stops in the middle?

Comment: I deleted the httpcache and it seems to work.